# Radio Button Binding Problem

Tags: c#, winforms

I am encountering a problem with the binding of database values to radio buttons on my form. I have a quiz, and in my database I have columns for each of the possible answers, as well as a column for the correct answer.

However, on every question that appears on my form, the correct answer is always the first radio button, even though the value in the 'correct answer' column isn't always the same as the value in the first radio button.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Quiz_Test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    String chosenAnswer, correctAnswer;
    DataTable table;
    int questionNumber = 0;
    int correctAnswers = 0;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Desktop\\QuizQuestions.accdb";

        OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
        OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();

        conGet.Open();
        cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdGet.Connection = conGet;

        cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM QuizQuestions ORDER BY rnd()";

        OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Load(reader);
        int recordCount = table.Rows.Count;

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {

            labelQuestion.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Question"].ToString();
            radioButton1.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 1"].ToString();
            radioButton2.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 2"].ToString();
            radioButton3.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 3"].ToString();
            radioButton4.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 4"].ToString();
            correctAnswer = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Correct Answer"].ToString();
            recordCount++;
        } 
    conGet.Close();
    }

    private void btnGoToNextOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Desktop\\QuizQuestions.accdb";

        OleDbConnection conGet = new OleDbConnection(cnString);
        OleDbCommand cmdGet = new OleDbCommand();
        int recordCount = table.Rows.Count;

        {
            conGet.Open();

            cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmdGet.Connection = conGet;

            cmdGet.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM QuizQuestions ORDER BY rnd()"; // select all columns in all rows

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
        if (questionNumber < recordCount)
        {

           if (radioButton1.Checked)
           {
              chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 1"].ToString();
           }
           else if (radioButton2.Checked)
           {
              chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 2"].ToString();
           }
           else if (radioButton3.Checked)
           {
              chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 3"].ToString();
           }
           else if (radioButton4.Checked)
           {
              chosenAnswer = reader["Answer 4"].ToString();
           }

           if (questionNumber < recordCount)
           {

               if (chosenAnswer == reader["Correct Answer"].ToString())
               {
                   labelQuestion.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Question"].ToString();
                   radioButton1.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 1"].ToString();
                   radioButton2.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 2"].ToString();
                   radioButton3.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 3"].ToString();
                   radioButton4.Text = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Answer 4"].ToString();
                   correctAnswer = table.Rows[questionNumber]["Correct Answer"].ToString();
                   questionNumber++;
                   correctAnswers++;
               }
               else
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("This is incorrect");
               }
               }
               recordCount++;
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("You have finished the test. You have " + questionNumber + " answers correct");
           }
           }
      }
  }  
}
```

Comment: I can't see in your code where you are setting the binding or the checked value for the radiobutton.  You are checking if it's true, but I don't see where you are setting it.

Comment: Hello, that is all of my code, can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you keep incrementing the recordCount variable instead of the questionNumber variable.

You don't even need the recordCount variable, just use the table.Rows.Count property.

I think that should basically solve your problem, although you have some unused foreach looping going on, etc.

Comment: OK, I have changed that though it hasn't sorted out the problem